# Book or article recommendation about causality and counterfactuals

Tags: references, inference, causality, logic

I'd like to assign undergraduate students with little to no math experience an **article, short part of a book, or even a blog post about causality and counterfactual logic that is easy to understand**.

It seems that most articles and books are too advanced for undergraduate students unfamiliar with formal logic or statistics.

Comment: Look for books and articles by Don Rubin and Judea Pearl.

Comment: I think both are excellent writers but I'm not sure whether they have anything for more popular audiences. Do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: I think Chapt. 2 & 3 from Morgan & Winship's "Counterfactuals And Causal Inference" is great for what you want. They offer a good introduction to what the authors denote as part on: "*Counterfactuals, Potential Outcomes and Causal Graphs*". These opening chapters assume *very* little Maths. The draft from Hernán & Robins' "[Causal Inference](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/)" is very good too if you want to pick and choose specific topics but the first chapters take a while to get the counterfactuals in motion, it is better for the "graph" aspect of things.

Comment: Also *maybe* (depending on what you expect from the students) you want to consider the articles on [Counterfactual Theories of Causation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causation-counterfactual/) and [Probabilistic Causation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causation-counterfactual/) from the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy. The Maths/Stats requirements vary a lot within the text but on the plus side all students will have immediate access and it is quite throughout.

Comment: To be clear, there is no way to get people to understand logical or probabilistic models of causation without at least a little knowledge of logic or probability, respectively. So presenting some amount of background material may be inevitable.

Comment: You might be right, @Kodiologist. I do like the Stanford Encyclopedia entry. The historical approach to understanding causality is a really good idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two longer recommendations that might fit the bill (depending on exactly what no math experience means):

1. [Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/PRIMER/) by Judea Pearl,‎ Madelyn Glymour, and ‎ Nicholas P. Jewell - a short book that covers the basic problem, with the first chapter covering basic probability concepts
2. Scott Cunningham's [Causal Inference: A Mixtape](http://scunning.com/cunningham_mixtape.pdf) - a draft of a book with lots of great empirical examples done in Stata. Probably less demanding than the former.

Comment: Perhaps attacking this issue from a historical/philosophical approach is a more appropriate method. Pearl and Cunningham's books are fantastic introductions to the logic of causal inference though, but I assume no math experience at all with these students to be honest. One could take sections of the books and make them into a useful presentation of causality concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Pearl's [The Book of Why](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/046509760X) is coming out soon, it might be an interesting read for students without background in math but that want to get started in causality.  The Epilogue in Causality ([The Art and Science of Cause and Effect](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/causality2-epilogue.pdf)) has a nice philosophical overview of the topic and is also a good read.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the chapter "Causal Inference" of Larry Wasserman's *All of Statistics*. It's 13 pages long, it has a few exercises, and it covers the counterfactual approach to causal modeling in a way that only requires basic knowledge of mathematical statistics (e.g., conditional probability). As a bonus, the following chapter covers the DAG approach to causal models, if you want to throw that in.

Comment: I like Wasserman but I'd like to, as much as possible, avoid any math whatsoever (this isn't technically a stats class) and I think DAGs get complicated quickly. I'd like the students to understand the intuition behind causality before getting into modeling.